# Untoggle *all* legend items in an Altair chart in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, toggle, legend, altair

I'm trying to create a chart with Altair in a Jupyter notebook. It's basically a line-chart of various currency values over time. I included my code below.

I can toggle currencies using the legend, and all is cool. I have one annoyance though: once I untoggle the last currency, all **lines** will be **disabled** (greyed out) while all **legend items** become **enabled**. I'd rather have all legend items greyed out as well once I untoggle the last currency, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Generate sample data with timestamps and numeric values for currencies
np.random.seed(42)
num_points = 50
date_today = datetime.now()
date_list = [date_today - timedelta(days=x) for x in range(num_points)]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Timestamp': date_list * 3,  # Three currencies
    'Currency': ['USD'] * num_points + ['EUR'] * num_points + ['GBP'] * num_points,
    'Value': np.random.randint(30, 70, size=num_points * 3)  # Random values
})

# Enable Altair to render charts in the notebook
alt.renderers.enable('default')

# Define a selection for the legend with toggle enabled
selection = alt.selection_point(fields=['Currency'], bind='legend', toggle='true', empty=False)

# Define the chart with the selection
chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x='Timestamp:T',
    y='Value:Q',
    color=alt.condition(selection, 'Currency:N', alt.value('#F0F0F0')),
    tooltip=['Timestamp:T', 'Currency:N', 'Value:Q']
).properties(
    width=800,
    height=400,
    title='Numeric Values Over Time per Currency'
).add_params(
    selection
)

# Show the interactive chart in the notebook
chart
```

Comment: At first glance, it seems like the legend opacity does not respect `empty=False`. Maybe it is something that is needed to be added in Vega-Lite; I'm not sure if there could be a wayto  hack around it with symbolFillColor and an expression maybe?